# Error al pasar de String a Long y a BigInteger para validar IBAN

Tags: java, string, parsear

Me da el error **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20389433376000130761142872"** en la línea 39. El IDE no me señala ningún error hasta que no lo ejecuto.

No se si estoy parseandolo bien, en principio lo paso a long para poderlo coger como BigInteger.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E09BankAccountCodeValidator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Instances
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Vars
    boolean ibanFormatFlag = true;

    do {
        System.out.print("[?] Introduce a spanish IBAN: ");
        String ibanStr = sc.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
        // Check IBAN's format
        if (ibanStr.substring(0, 2).equals("ES") && ibanStr.length() == 24) {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 23; i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(ibanStr.charAt(i))) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    ibanFormatFlag = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ibanFormatFlag = false;
        }
        System.out.println("[+] IBAN format check: PASSED");
        System.out.println("[+] Original IBAN: " + ibanStr);
        // Validate country code control digits
        String ibanStrReordered = ibanStr.substring(4, 24).concat(ibanStr.substring(0, 4)).replace("ES", "1428");
        System.out.println("[+] Ordered IBAN string format: " + ibanStrReordered);
        long ibanOrderedLong = Long.parseLong(ibanStrReordered);
        BigInteger ibanOrdered = BigInteger.valueOf(ibanOrderedLong);
        System.out.println("[+] Ordered IBAN biginteger format: " + ibanOrdered);
        int resto = ibanOrdered.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(97)).intValue();
        System.out.println("[+] Resto: " + resto);


    } while(ibanFormatFlag);
    sc.close();
    closeApp();

}

public static void closeApp() {
    System.out.println("[!] Wrong spanish IBAN format.");
    System.out.println("[+] IBAN format: ESNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN");
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

No se si estoy parseandolo mal pero en la linea 39 salta siempre.

Output:

[?] Introduce a spanish IBAN: es7220389433376000130761

[+] IBAN format check: PASSED

[+] Original IBAN: ES7220389433376000130761

[+] Ordered IBAN string format: 20389433376000130761142872

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20389433376000130761142872"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
    at

ejercicios_cadenas_de_texto.E09BankAccountCodeValidator.main(E09BankAccountCodeValidator.java:39)

Comment: El stacktrace te dice que el problema no es con el BigInteger, sino con el Long

Comment: ¿Porqué razón querrías usar un valor numérico para el código [IBAN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number)? ¿Realizarás operaciones matemáticas con el mismo? Mi sugerencia es que lo trates como un tipo `String`. En mi experiencia no tiene ninguna utilidad convertirlo a un formato numérico ya que no hay (hasta donde yo conozco) operaciones numéricas que puedas realizar con dicho código. Saludos

Comment: Quiero hacer cálculos con el como aplicar el mod 97 al mismo para verificar los dígitos de control.

Comment: Mantengo que no necesitas convertirlo a valor numérico. Aunque ya tienes una respuesta aceptada, te daré otra mostrando la forma de hacerlo sin usar el `cast` a un valor numérico ni usar una librería como BigInteger. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi [último comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363166/error-al-pasar-de-string-a-long-y-a-biginteger-para-validar-iban#comment652178_363166) dije que no veo la razón de realizar la [conversión de tipo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversi%C3%B3n_de_tipos) para obtener el valor numérico del código [IBAN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number).

Si bien esta afirmación no es del todo cierta (ya veremos porqué), me refiero a que es un gasto de recursos innecesario el tener que implementar un tipo [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) o incluso usar alguna librería como [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) para realizar la comprobación de un código IBAN.

En la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363166/error-al-pasar-de-string-a-long-y-a-biginteger-para-validar-iban#comment652174_363166) a mi primer [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363166/error-al-pasar-de-string-a-long-y-a-biginteger-para-validar-iban#comment652173_363166) planteas que necesitas *aplicar el mod 97* a dicha representación numérica.

Tomando eso en cuenta, veamos como implementar esa comprobación sin el uso de `BigInteger` o la necesidad de almacenar un valor tipo `Long` tan alto.

Un código IBAN se compone de un máximo de 34 caracteres, siendo los primeros 4 caracteres un código que identifica al país (mediante 2 letras del alfabeto) seguido de 2 números de control para comprobar la validez de todo el código.

Por lo tanto, quitando estos primeros 4 dígitos, podemos tener un valor numérico de hasta 30 cifras para un código IBAN.

El tipo `Long` de Java, puede representar hasta 19 cifras enteras, y se queda corto para manejar un código IBAN de países como España (por ejemplo).

**Módulo 97**

El [algoritmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Modulo_operation_on_IBAN) para validar un código IBAN cuando no disponemos de la capacidad de trabajar con tantos dígitos, establece que se puede realizar la validación mediante un proceso iterativo, tomando partes de la totalidad del código y calculando el valor del módulo 97 sobre una construcción manual de dichas partes.

Veamos el algoritmo:(tomado de Wikipedia)

1. Comenzando por la izquierda del valor *D*, se toman los primeros 9 dígitos y se forma una nueva cifra la cual llamaremos *N*.
2. Calculamos `N mod 97`.
3. Se construye una nueva cifra de 9 elementos concatenando el resultado del paso 2 con las siguientes 7 cifras del valor *D* que aún no han sido procesadas. Si hay menos de 7 cifras pero al menos hay una (en *D*), el nuevo valor de *N* tendrá menos de 9 dígitos.
4. Repetir los pasos 2 - 3 hasta que todos los dígitos de *D* hayan sido procesados.

Sencillo, ¿cierto? y lo mejor de todo, no se necesita una librería como `BigInteger`.

**¿Porqué construir las cifras con 9 dígitos?**

Parece que alguien se inventó ese número, pero lo cierto es que no. La razón por la que debemos construir cifras de hasta 9 dígitos es sencilla.

Todo valor entero en base 10 tiene una representación en base 2. Así el número `3` en base decimal se puede representar como `11` en binario (siendo estos los valores de los dígitos que multiplican las potencias de base 2 en la suma de las mismas).

```
 3 (decimal) => 3*(10^0) == 1*(2^1) + 1*(2^0) => 11 (binario)
15 (decimal) => 1*(10^1) + 5*(10^0) == 1*(2^3) + 1*(2^2) + 1*(2^1) + 1*(2^0) => 1111 (binario)
```

Esto nos conduce a lo siguiente:

```
si x < 10^9 => x < 2^31
```

Lo que significa que si un valor `X` tiene máximo 9 dígitos, entonces podrá ser representado correctamente por un tipo Entero de 32 bits, lo que es un estándar en el mundo de la informática hoy en día.

**Ejemplo**

Tomemos un ejemplo práctico del algoritmo anterior.

Suponiendo que el usuario introduce el siguiente código IBAN:

```
ES07 0012 0345 0300 0006 7890
```

*Tomado de [Cálculo del IBAN](https://portal.kutxabank.es/cs/Satellite/kb/es/kutxabank_en_sepa/calculo_del_iban/documento)*

Una vez realizadas las comprobaciones preliminares, debemos construir nuestra cifra (*D*), la cual queda establecida como:

```
String D = "00120345030000067890142807";
```

1. Tomamos los primeros 9 dígitos, empezando por la izquierda:
   `String N = D.substring(0,9); // "001203450"`
2. Calculamos el valor de `N mod 97`:
   `int remainder = Integer.valueOf(N) % 97; // 68`
3. Creamos un nuevo valor de *N* usando el resultado del paso 2 y concatenando los siguientes 7 dígitos de *D*:
   `N = String.valueOf(remainder).concat(D.substring(pos, pos + 7)); // "683000006"`
4. Repetimos el paso 2 hasta que no queden valores por usar en *D*.

Una forma de implementar este algoritmo, a modo ilustrativo y sin pensar en el desempeño, sería la Siguiente:

```java
// Función que devuelve el valor de D mod 97
private static int calcMod97(String D) {
  String N = D.substring(0, 9); // Primera construcción de N
  int remainder;
  int pos = 9;  // Posición inicial para extraer los siguientes digitos de D
  int end = D.length() - 1; // posición máxima que podemos alcanzar en D
  boolean last = false; // flag para saber si estamos en el último cálculo
  while(true) {
    remainder = Integer.valueOf(N) % 97; // cálculo del resto
    if(!last) { // si no es el último cálculo creamos nuevo valor de N
      if((pos + 7) < end) { // si podemos extraer 7 dígitos
        N = String.valueOf(remainder).concat(D.substring(pos, pos + 7));
        pos = pos + 7;
      } else { // si no podemos extraer 7 dígitos
        N = String.valueOf(remainder).concat(D.substring(pos));
        pos = end;
        last = true; // este será el último cálculo
      }
    } else {
      // salimos
      break;
    }
  }
  return remainder;
}
```

Puedes ver una implementación de este código en el siguiente [enlace](https://ideone.com/nGFA0j).

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta que lo pases a `Long`, el propio constructor de `BigInteger` acepta un `String`:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String iban = "20389433376000130761142872";
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(iban);
    System.out.println(big);
  }
```

Más info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevaba un rato ahí y no localizaba el fallo, me lo ha solucionado y aligerado el código.

Answer (score 2):

No podrá convertir ese valor tipo String en un long, ya que sobrepasa su valor máximo `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, al escribirlo en el IDE no te va a saltar el error ya que eso
se comprueba en tiempo de ejecución.